# Distributed Text Editor: multiple users editing a text file concurrently

Tags: java, io, distributed, synchronized

I am working on a distributed system project. I am required to create a program that allow multiple users to edit on the same text file concurrently. I have been looking around online for a relatively simple solution but I haven't found one. I've read about BlockingQueue but that doesn't make much sense to me. I have talked to my TA and he suggested that each client will have a copy of the text file, which will they edit. Those sub-files will then be merged to the main copy. However, the problem is that I won't be able to update those sub-files while they are editing the text file.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it you want an online text editor with which you can modify files concurrently and the updates should happen as real-time as possible.

Here is what I would do:

1. If a user opens a file he receives a copy of it and the user is added to the list of users which have opened this file.
2. After a user makes a change, wait X seconds to accumulate further changes and then send them to the server.
3. The server processes the change requests for a file one after the other (different files can be done in parallel of course and it can also be done more intelligently by splitting files into chunks which can be processed independently in parallel too, at least on the server side [this is only partially true, two changes can be processed in parallel if the intersection of the set of affected chunks in change A and change B is empty])
4. A change request is either acceppted and all the changes are broadcastest to all user that have the file opened or the change is refused. This can be pretty complicated. The easiest way is to keep track with a version number and refuse all changes that come from older versions. (If you have a version number for each chunk and the size of the chunks is small, you will only run into rejections if two or more people are working at the almost same location in a document at the same time. But it will be quite some work, consider you will have to split/merge/delete/insert chunks if they become too big or small.)